# Should I include file extensions when setting registry items?

Tags: php, registry

In two instances I define registry items which I specify the name of the template and css files.  Should I include the file extension when setting the registry items, or exclude them as I am currently doing with my application?  What do you advise?

```
 $registryItems['template']    = 'default'; //Name of .tpl file
 $registryItems['stylesheet']  = 'default'; //Name of .css file
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS file doesn't necessarily have to have the .css extension. The same is true for templates. They could as well end with .txt. Therefore if you do not include the extension you have to implement them as conventions in your code with the effect that all files of a type must have the same extension. Strictness vs. flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at comparable entries written by someone who knows the proper conventions.  Maybe Microsoft has some entries to look at?